# How to implement reactive programming in angular with Observable store state management?

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

I am using @CodeWithDan/Observable store package for state management. However while started to play with it, there was no help on how to have a reactive programming using the observable stores. Is there any help links out there to get an idea on how we can manage state with reactive programming>

Comment: Your question is out of scope sorry

Comment: you may want to use NgRx to manage the state inside your angular app. https://ngrx.io/